# Screen goes dark when Facebook interstitial ad is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-audience-network

I'm implementing interstitial ads from Facebook in my iOS Swift app. The interstitial shows correctly, but when it is dismissed the view controller from which the ad was presented from shows up for a fraction of a second, then the screen goes dark.

I'm following the instructions from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/ad-formats/interstitial/ios)

I've implemented facebook ads in another app successfully, now I'm doing the same thing but the above behavior happens.

The app has multiple view controller's and it doesn't matter from which the ad is presented, it always results in the same behavior.

Does anybody has any idea why this might happen, because currently I'm clueless?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `FBAudienceNetwork` SDK. This was an issue with an older version.